# display type, CSS

Tags: html, css, display

HTML code

```
<div class="container">
        <section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
            <div class="section-subtitle">
                Mening ishlarim
                <span class="blur-line"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="section-title">
                Mening oxirgi <br>
                Ishlarimni ko'ring
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-items">
                <div class="portfolio-item">
                    <img class="portfolio-item__image" src="images/p1.jpg" alt="Portfolio Image 1">
                    <div class="portfolio-item__overlay"></div>
                    <div class="portfolio-item__info">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="#">Portfolio item 1</a>
                            <p>Ishim haqida</p>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
/* Portfolio section */
.portfolio {
    padding: 100px 0;
}

.portfolio-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio-item__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(19,69,230,0.9);
}

.portfolio-item__info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:44px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

I am following a video tutorial to learn CSS and building a demo-website as a project. When I change the display property of the portfolio-item class in the css code to inline-block, the size of the portfolio-item__overlay changes to the same size of the image that comes before it in the html code. I am wondering why it takes the size of its sibling element. The height and width is 100% and it should inherit its parent's size as its position is absolute.
I am new to HTML and CSS. Please, explain.

Comment: Because inline-blocks don't have a width like that - they might spread out over multiple lines etc... So it's width relies on the content within, which is now just the image?

Comment: block elements take the full available width by default, whereas inline(-block) elements are supposed to shrink to the width their content requires.

Comment: @CBroe, if the image is a sibling of the overlay item, how can the image be the content of it?

Comment: _"how can the image be the content of it?"_ - who said it was? `.portfolio-item` is the element that you modified to be inline-block, and the image is part of the content of _that_.

Comment: `.portfolio-item__overlay` is positioned absolute, so it does not influence the width of its parent. So `.portfolio-item__image` and the text content of `.portfolio-item__info` determine how wide the inline-block parent needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the display property of an element to inline-block, it behaves like an inline element but allows you to set its width and height.

In your code, the .portfolio-item element becomes as wide as its content, which is the image. Therefore, the overlay element adjusts to match that size.